# How to batch read sqs messages inside beanstalk worker

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

Our web application running on elastic beanstalk logs activity of incoming request to a database. We want to decouple the dB logging from the request processing path, so that response time can be sped up. We decided to use sqs queues and beanstalk worker. The idea is to queue the logging event to sqs, and have the worker receive the events and let it do the logging to the dB.

Now the need is to optimize the dB logging operation and avoid creating one connection per message in the queue. From my understanding the sqs daemon would Call the worker for each message, is there a way to have the daemon send messages in a batch, so that there's only one message and it's body has contents of all messages?

Or do we need to use a secondary queue or write a custom sqs message aggregator that processes n messages from the queue and then sends one batch message to another queue and that then gets written to the dB once?

We are using php and mysql

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, defaultly you cannot. The daemon calls your application for each message. 
What you can do might be that you cache the messages locally (assuming you are using single instance instead of auto scaling one) in a file (locking system for multi-processing) and then uses the scheduling of ELB cronjob to retrieve information from the file then do your DB operations every a certain amount of time. Thus, you can do that DB operation in a batch.

If you want to use auto scaling with multiple instances, you might need to use another messaging which is a waste compared with another option. This option is you write your own code using based off aws sdk to receive/delete from SQS in a batch and then update your database.